# Inline asm (32) emulation of move (copy memory) command

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, memcpy

I have two two-dimensional arrays with dynamic sizes (guess that's the proper wording). I copy the content of first one into the other using:

```
    dest:=copy(src,0,4*x*y);
    // src,dest:array of array of longint; x,y:longint;
    // setlength(both arrays,x,y);  //x and y are max 15 bit positive!
```

It works. However I'm unable to reproduce this in asm. I tried the following variations to no avail... Could someone enlighten me...

```
    MOV ESI,src; MOV EDI,dest; MOV EBX,y; MOV EAX,x; MUL EBX; 
    PUSH DS; POP ES; MOV ECX,EAX; CLD; REP MOVSD;
```

Also tried with LEA (didn't expect that to work since it should fetch the pointer address not the array address), no workie, and tried with:

```
    p1:=@src[0,0]; p2:=@dest[0,0]; //being no-type pointers
    MOV ESI,p1; MOV EDI,p2... (the same asm)
```

Hints pls? Btw it's delphi 6. The error is, of course, access violation.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? An asm version is unlikely to be significantly faster.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Why people need to reply to questions with *Why?* :) If this where a *XY problem* it could be justified but I don't think it is. The OP may just be curios or may want to challenge themselves.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: That's the point: we don't know the OP's motivation for doing this. Knowing that would allow us to write a focused answer. - I see you've responded, and that's fine.

Comment: Have a look at the fastcode source for `system.move`, see: http://fastcode.sourceforge.net/ and/or get the source for fastmove at: http://fastcode.sourceforge.net/FastcodeFileDownloads/FastMove303.zip

Comment: @MargaretBloom The "why" question is valid. Often askers get upset when their motivation is questioned. But also quite often it transpires that there was a misconception behind that motivation. Perhaps that's not the case here, but when we ask "why" questions it is usually so that we can attempt to help as well as possible.

Comment: I've realized that the delphi code didn't work. The copy command must be phrased:
`for i:=0 to pred(x) do dest[i]:=copy(src[i],0,4*y);`
Regarding the why issue, I don't ask why people answer. Why do they ask why I question? Nobody is obliged to ask or answer. Oh, I question, just because I want to rule the world, nothing to be alarmed...

Answer (score 2):

This is really a <strike>two-fold</strike> three-fold question.

1. What's the structure of a dynamic array.
2. Which instructions in asm will copy the array.
3. I'm throwing random assembler at the CPU, why doesn't it work?

**Structure of a dynamic array**
See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Internal_Data_Formats
To quote:

> Dynamic Array Types
>
> On the 32-bit platform, a dynamic-array variable occupies 4 bytes of memory (and 8 bytes on 64-bit) that contain a pointer to the dynamically allocated array. When the variable is empty (uninitialized) or holds a zero-length array, the pointer is nil and no dynamic memory is associated with the variable. For a nonempty array, the variable points to a dynamically allocated block of memory that contains the array in addition to a 32-bit (64-bit on Win64) length indicator and a 32-bit reference count. The table below shows the layout of a dynamic-array memory block.
>
> Dynamic array memory layout (32-bit and 64-bit)

```
Offset 32-bit    -8       -4       0 
Offset 64-bit   -12       -8       0
contents      refcount  count    start of data
```

So the dynamic array variable is a pointer to the middle of the above structure.

**How do I access this in asm**

Let's assume the array holds records of type TMyRec

you'll need to run this code for every inner array in the outer array to do the deep copy. I leave this as an exercise for the reader. (you can do the other part in pascal).

```
type
  TDynArr: array of TMyRec;

procedure SlowButBasicMove(const Source: TDynArr; var dest);
asm
  //insert register pushes, see below.
  mov esi,Source          //esi = pointer to source data
  mov edi,Dest            //edi = pointer to dest
  sub esi,8               
  mov ebx,[esi]           //ebx = refcount (just in case)
  mov ecx,[esi+4]         //ecx = element count
  mov edx,SizeOf(TMyRec)  //anywhere from 1 to zillions
  mul ecx,edx             //==ecx=number of bytes in array.
  //// now we can start moving 
  xor ebx,ebx             //ebx =0
  add eax,8               //eax = @data
  @loop:
  mov eax,[esi+ebx]       //Get data from source
  mov [edi+ebx],esi       //copy it to dest
  add ebx,4               //4 bytes at a time
  cmp ebx,ecx             //is ebx> number of bytes?
  jle loop 
  //Done copying.
  //insert register pops, see below
end;
```

That's the copy done, however in order for the system not to crash, you need to save and restore the non volatile registers (all but EAX, ECX, EDX), see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Program_Control

```
push ebx
push esi
push edi
--- insert code shown above
//restore non-volatile registers
pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx  //note the restoring must happen in the reverse order of the push.
```

See the Jeff Dunteman's book `assembly step by step` if you're completely new to asm.

You will get access violations if:

- you try to read from a wrong address.
- you try to write to a wrong adress.
- you read past the end of the array.
- you write to memory you haven't claimed before using GetMem or whatever means.
- if you write past the end of your buffer.
- if you do not restore all non-volatile registers

Remember you're directly dealing with the CPU. Delphi will not assist you in any way.

Really fast code will use some form of SSE to move 16bytes per instruction in an unrolled loop, see the above mentioned fastcode for examples of optimized assembler.

**Random assembler**
In assembler you need to know **exactly** what you're what to do, how and what the CPU does.
Set a breakpoint and run your code. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and behold the CPU-debug window.
This will allow you to see the code Delphi generates.
You can single step through the code to see what the CPU does.
see: http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/index.html
For more reading.

Comment: On Intel IvB and later, `rep movsb` is actually very fast for aligned inputs, and competes well with an SSE loop for blocks of 128B or larger, IIRC.  On earlier CPUs, `rep movsq` and then cleanup is better.  (That's what Linux's memcpy does, on CPUs where `rep movs` is worth using at all (I think not AMD).)  @mio: also have a look at http://agner.org/optimize/ and the x86 tag wiki for other links.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the fact that `rep mov` has very variable performance from one processor to another makes it a no-go in my book. I don't like to optimize just for recent Intel's. The hand crafted loop (some additional optimization is needed here, granted) always performs well.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way to go.  Not losing out on much, except for very large memcpy (where `rep movs` on Intel avoids RFOs when the stores miss in cache).  Something that's good on one CPU but bad on another is only acceptable if you use runtime CPU dispatching.  For something like memcpy that's used everywhere, you need something that avoids a compare-and-branch or indirect call at every call site (e.g. dynamic linker tricks, or JIT-style overwriting the bytes that the `memcpy` symbol points to).  This usually isn't worth the effort.

Comment: I thank you for the detailed answer although a sufficient one was: "you overlooked the fact that array of array is not the same as 2d-array". Regarding the random assembler, it's a very complex question. Most people go through their entire lifes without realizing almost anything, so a little random assembler can't be as bad as you claim.

Comment: `mul ecx,edx` looks like a typo for `imul ecx,edx` (unless Delphi's assembler actually has an alias / pseudo-instruction).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Arrays differ from Static Arrays, especially when it comes to multi-dimensionality.

Refer to [this reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Static_Array_Types) for internal formats.

The point is that an `Array Of Array Of LongInt` of dimensions `X` and `Y` (in this order!) is a *pointer to an array of X pointers that point to an array of Y LongInts*.

Since it seems, from your comments, that you have already allocated the space for all elements in `Dest`, I assume you want to do a Deep Copy.

Here a sample program, where the assembly as been made as simple as possible for the sake of clarity.

```
Program Test;

Var Src, Dest: Array Of Array Of LongInt;
    X, Y, I, J: Integer;
Begin

   X := 4;
   Y := 2;

   setLength(Src, X, Y);
   setLength(Dest, X, Y);

   For I := 0 To X-1 Do
      For J := 0 To Y-1 Do
         Src[I,J] := I*Y + J;


   {$ASMMODE intel}
   Asm
       cld                         ;Be sure movsd increments the registers
       mov esi, DWORD PTR [Src]    ;Src pointer
       mov edi, DWORD PTR [Dest]   ;Dest pointer

       mov ecx, DWORD PTR [X]      ;Repeat for X times
                                   ;The number of elements in Src

      @_copy:
       push esi                    ;Save these for later
       push edi 
       push ecx 

       mov ecx, DWORD PTR [Y]      ;Repeat for Y times
                                   ;The number of element in a Src[i] array
       mov edi, DWORD PTR [edi]    ;Get the pointer to the Dest[i] array
       mov esi, DWORD PTR [esi]    ;Get the pointer to the Src[i] array
       rep movsd                   ;Copy sub array

       pop ecx                     ;Restore
       pop edi 
       pop esi 

       add esi, 04h                ;Go from Src[i] to Src[i+1]
       add edi, 04h                ;Go from Dest[i] to Dest[i+1]
      loop @_copy

   End;


   For I := 0 To X-1 Do
      Begin
         WriteLn();

         For J := 0 To Y-1 Do
            Begin
               Write(' ');
               Write(Dest[I,J]);
            End;
      End;
End.
```

**Note 1** This source code is intended to be compile with *freepascal*.
Donation of *Spare Time(TM)* for downloading and installing *Delphi* are welcome!

**Note 2** This source code is for *illustration purpose only*, it is pretty obvious, it has already been stated above, but somehow not everybody got it.
If the OP wanted a fast way to copy the array, they should have stated so.

**Note 3** I don't save the clobbered registers, this is **bad practice**, my bad; I forgot, as there are no subroutines, no optimizations and no reason for the compiler to pass data in the registers between the two fors.
This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: The `rep` instructions have horrible performance for short arrays, better to use a specially crafted loop. (and no need to push/pop ecx), and never never never use `loop`.

Comment: "a pointer to an array of X pointers that point to an array of Y LongInts" 
That solves my question, I guess, I will check your code later but I believe this info should be sufficient. And, of course, I might switch to single-dimension arrays and calculate indexes.
I couldn't agree more on the why comment, which I see too often when I visit this site. Of course I don't need this to copy a block but to perform more complex operations and want to learn how to access the data.

Comment: You're not saving the registers, which will cause an AV, the `cld` is not needed. in Delphi `CLD` is always the case. and {$asmmode} is a freepascal directive, not Delphi.

Comment: @miodrag: You should always explain what you *really* want to know, at least as background to the question you actually ask.  It helps a lot for potential answerers.  There might be different ways that perform well in opposite situations, and the answer can spend more time on the one that's appropriate for your case.  Or any number of other tradeoffs that an answerer might consider, but that you don't know about because otherwise you wouldn't be asking.  And of course, "how should I do <something foolish>" makes people want to spend time telling you why it's a bad plan.

Comment: @Johan, This is a sample program. It is intended to be trivial and close to what the OP have tried so they can inspect it and easily figure out the layout of the data. Thanks for pointing out the *{$asmmode}* directive, I'll add a note.

Comment: That's cool, but you will have an AV, because you used code that is meant to be run on Unix where `edi` and `esi` are volatile. However on Windows they are not and not saving them will give an AV., -1 because of that.